# how to find perticular building boundaries on map using latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, coordinates, openstreetmap, building, boundary

basically i have one latitude and longitude of building but i am trying to get whole boundaries's co-ordinates so i can display polygon line to whole building.

Here,
I am trying to get building boundaries or (upper Latitude + Lower longitude) when i click on map. so i'll get two point which is latitude and longitude . using this two point i am trying to get whole co-ordinate of building so i can draw polygon on perfect building.

if another solution for this question you can tell me.